# How to show fragment or activity above the pattern lock?

Tags: android

I wanted to show a fragment or Activity above the pattern Lock in android Phone. Example if you are using any music player, you can see the music player above the lock pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add OverLay for this case:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```